# Suppressing Input box of an application through vba

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I am trying to run an exe using shell command in vba.

The problem is when it prompts for user input, is there a way I can suppress it or pass enter key to complete running that exe application.

I have used shell "xxx.exe" in my application.

I need to suppress the prompt from this exe.

Comment: You'll have to use a couple of the system libraries.

Comment: What kind of .exe is this? Does it give you parameters? Maybe you can pass a parameter for turning off prompts and warnings

Comment: An `.exe` file is an application done by someone else. To reach what you meant to reach, you should: 1) Know if any API has been developed by the application developer to let it receive external commands by VBA; 2) If yes, then you should know what are the commands to pass the inputs to. Without these information, it is impossible to tell you; now, you're just launching the process, not interacting with it. If the application you run is a famous one, try searching for any VBA API on Google; if it's a in-house app, then try to contact the developer and see if he/she provides API.

Comment: @Mascaro: what system libraries can be used ?

Comment: @EngJon: It is an application used to generate reports. Yes, it has some parameters too. I Had tried using some parameters but didn't work. Could you suggest what parameters I can use.

Comment: @Matteo: It's an external application , will check on API with them. however, was checking the VBA API here: http://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/hip/us/hip_us_pearsonhighered/samplechapter/0321262506.pdf   thanks.